# avoid asynchronous issues when assign a property inside an observable

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I am assigning the value of a property inside an observable:

```
this.sessionQuery.privateUser$.pipe(
  pluck('role')
).subscribe( userRole => {
  this.userRole = userRole; // userRole = true;
})
```

My property userRole now have the value true. The problem is that I need to use userRole property immediately with the value **true** into other methods but when other methods get executed, userRole value is still undefined. I am aware, this should be a problem of asynchronous but I would like to have the value true immediately to keep working with that value inside other methods.

I tried executing the rest of methods after the userRole assignation inside the subscribe and that works but for code organization reasons I need to place the rest of methods outside the subscription.

Maybe other solution is to force the code execution to wait until first subscription finishes

These are other methods placed below the subscription that use the properly:

```
isRepairOrCustomer(): string {
if (this.userRole && this.currentTaskRole === 'RepairCentre') {
  return 'Private';
} else if (!this.userRole && this.currentTaskRole === 'Customer') {
  return 'Public';
}
```

}

```
private setCurrentTaskTitle() {
if (this.userRole) {
  this.titleTask = this.internalStatus;
} else {
  this.titleTask = this.customerStatus;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share more code with us? Mainly the functions that you need to use

Comment: I just added two methods that use the property

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait for the subscribe to return the value, you have two choices. One of them is to bring your call inside the subscription, like this:

```js
this.sessionQuery.privateUser$.pipe(
  pluck('role')
).subscribe( userRole => {
  this.userRole = userRole; // userRole = true;
  const aux1 = this.isRepairOrCustomer()
  this.setCurrentTaskTitle()
})
```

Or transform the subscribe to a promise, like this:

```js
const userRole = await this.sessionQuery.privateUser$.pipe(
  pluck('role')
).toPromise()

this.userRole = userRole; // userRole = true;
const aux1 = this.isRepairOrCustomer()
this.setCurrentTaskTitle()
```

And remember to add the async before the function where you are using these calls

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that:

```
class MyClass {
  
  ...

  userRole$: Obeserable<boolean> = this.sessionQuery.privateUser$
    .pipe(pluck('role'))

  // I don't know your types of 'internalStatus' and 'customerStatus'
  // because of that the any
  titleTask$: Observable<any> = this.userRole$.pipe(
    map((userRole) => userRole ? this.internalStatus : this.customerStatus)
  )

  isRepairOrCustomer$: Observable<string> = this.userRole$.pipe(
    map((userRole) => {
      if (userRole && this.currentTaskRole === 'RepairCentre') {
        return 'Private'
      } else if (!userRole && this.currentTaskRole === 'Customer') {
        return 'Public'
      }
    })
  )

  ...

}
```

In your template you can use the `async` pipe to subscribe to the observables.